# Why is only one button appearing when I dynamically add two?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-button, dynamically-generated

I have this code in a method where `listOfTeamsJoined` definitely has two teams.

```
for (Team t : listOfTeamsJoined) 
{ 
     makeTeamButton(t.display_name);
}
```

which calls this method:

```
private void makeTeamButton(String teamName) 
{
       Button newTeamButton = new Button(this);
       LinearLayout teamButtonHolder = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.availableTeamsList);

       newTeamButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
               LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
               LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
       ));

       newTeamButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00C272"));
       newTeamButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF "));
       newTeamButton.setText(teamName);

       teamButtonHolder.addView(newTeamButton);
   }
```

The problem is that only one of them will show. I suspect that either one is being replaced by the other or they are appearing on top of each other. However, since I am using `LinearLayout`, I don't think they should be appearing on top of each other and as far as I know, `addView` doesn't replace views, it just appends them. However, if I reorder the list then I can make the other appear, they just won't appear together.

Comment: Check your LinearLayout Orientation.

Comment: Wow, I feel silly, that was the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default orientation is horizontal. And you're using a width of `MATCH_PARENT` for the widths of both buttons. This means that your first button will take the whole width leaving nothing for the second one, thus making it not visible.

Set the orientation manually if you want your `LinearLayout` to be vertical like this:

```
teamButtonHolder.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

If you wish to keep it horizontal, then just invert the width and height to be `WRAP_CONTENT` and `MATCH_PARENT`, respectively. And that'll work too but it'll show them side by side.

Answer (score 0):

What orientation has your LinearLayout? Seems to be it's set to horizontal and you want them placed on top of each other so "vertical" should be the right choice here.

Answer (score 0):

You are add two new button dynamically, But it show one button while you see, because it happened due to overlap to each others. so give some margin or padding to each others, then you will see it. I hope it would be help to you.

Answer (score 0):

As you set your buttons width as `match_parent` like below:

```
newTeamButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
           LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
           LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
   ));
```

you have to set your `LinearLayout`'s orientation as `vertical`;

But if you want to set those buttons as `horizontally` then set the width param as `wrap_content` like:

```
newTeamButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
           LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
           LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
   ));
```